# Is There a Limit to The Energy-density Confined to a Black-hole Structure, Consisting of a Schwarzschild Sphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, momentum

Imagine two particles repeatedly colliding with increasing momentum,like a dense collection of particles confined within the envelope of a collapsing star that's close to becoming a black hole.

Is it possible that hyper-dense, particle matter confined within the envelope of a developing Schwarzschild sphere (whatever its size) can no longer be transformed into the particle momentum as particle velocity approaches the speed of light?  Special relativity does NOT allow an inertial system to exceed the speed of light; and particles colliding at speeds approaching that of light cannot absorb a further increase in the momentum produced by gravitational forces. At this critical point, can gravitational energy be transformed directly into radiation rather than particle momentum?

Answer (score 2):

It is not believed that high momentum interactions are untenable, however there is a limit to the ability of our best quantum theories to understand and calculate such interactions.

Specifically in quantum field theory used in particle accelerator interactions a so-called "ultraviolet cut off" is used in the calculation so momentum beyond a certain level is ignored.

It is believed that at extreme high momentum interactions such a large mass-energy density is created at the point of interaction that quantum gravity effects become important in understanding the interactions.

Comment: B. Greetham: Thanks for your input.  I'm trying to get information about the kind of hyper-momentum one might find in colliding particles trapped in an object with a radius approaching that of a Schwarzschild sphere (a Black-hole).  please see this paper:    https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/a98rov/black_hole_radiation_model_new/

Comment: Voici an excerpt that ties in with this discussion; and I welcome all comments and criticism.

Comment: "At the final nanosecond in the formation of a black hole, essentially all of the matter confined within the envelope of a developing Schwarzschild sphere (whatever its size) can no longer be transformed into particle kinetic-energy.  Special relativity does NOT allow an inertial system to exceed the speed of light; and particles colliding at speeds approaching that of light cannot absorb a further increase in the momentum produced by gravitational forces.  At this point, gravitational energy is transformed directly into radiation (entropy) rather than particle momentum."

Comment: @RobertO Special relativity emphatically does *not* limit the momentum (nor the kinetic energy) of bodies, it only limits their velocity.

Comment: @PM...Yes, there is NO limit to the amount of energy that nature will allow; but there Is a limit to the energy density allowed by nature.  This is expressed by F(planck) = 2E/r(bh), where E/r = constant.